# Jquery add method function should not fire based on condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

In my form having

```
 Payment Method : Dropdown [value  -1, 1, 2]
 Tax Type: Dropdown [value 1 0 2]
 Sake Tax Amount : textbox
 submitButton
```

I have customized function (addMethod) for saletax amount based on condition.

**My Requirement is:**
When I select dropdown[Payment Method] value -1 or 1 then validate should not fire on that saletax amount. Otherwise If I select dropdown[Payment Method] value 2 then validate fire based on the taxtype value. In this case (dropdown[Payment Method] value 2) working fine for me but dropdown[Payment Method] value 1 or -1 that time also firing only addmethod function.It should not happen.

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/a7zQ6/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rules, change

```
taxAmount_validate: true
```

to

```
taxAmount_validate: {
                    depends: function(element) {return $('#ddlPaymentMethod :selected').val()=='2' }
                }
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7zQ6/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Finally i got solution from you help.

Comment: Here I have one more issue is there. I need to display separate message for "Taxable" and " Non taxable". Can you please any idea for this?

Comment: You can provide a callback function in the `messages` option. It can check the tax type and return the appropriate message.

Comment: I'm a beginner only. So, can you update this in that fiddle itself please?